# how to share video on facebook from website

Tags: facebook, share

any one know how to share video on facebook from website.

please help out.

this is my code.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'og.shares',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
    object: {
      'og:url': overrideLink,
      'og:title': overrideTitle,
      'og:description': overrideDescription,
      'og:video': overrideImage,
      'og:video:secure_url': overrideImage,
      'og:video:type': "video/mp4",
      'og:video:width': 600,
      'og:video:height': 350
    }
  })
});
```